Recent Files not displayed in File > Open Recent after saving and closing a new file
The recently saved file ("test.txt") does not appear in the "Open Recent" list. Instead, other files are displayed.
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a new file with any content in Kate.
Save the file with a unique name and close Kate.
Reopen Kate and navigate to File > Open Recent.
Observe that the recently saved file is not listed under "Open Recent".

Kate Version 23.08.5

Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-48-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
Memory: 31,3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
Product Name: MS-7C37
System Version: 2.0


I think it the recent list is only "per-session", and so once you close Kate, it's gone: https://kate-editor.org/2010/10/27/recent-files-menu-in-kate/

the problem stays over days. but now I clicked clean list, then the behavior was like expected. Maybe the problem will be there again when the recent file list gets full. idk
